# What is a web service URL when deployed on a Glassfish server?

Tags: web-services, glassfish, endpoint

I am migrating a web service from Tomee 1.6 to Glassfish 4.0

With Tomee, my web service endpoint was :

```
http://<server>:8080/<projectName>/webservices/<classname>
```

My questiion is : What is it with Glassfish ?

I have deployed my application without any error. Everything seems fine, but I don't know how to call the web service.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer myself : when you deploy the application in Glassfish, you have to read the messages on the console, and you can see something like:

```
listening at address at http://<server>:<port>/RefProduitService/RefProduit
```

That s the URL I was looking for.